# Saving array in file and then loading it in Octave? Error: struct cannot be indexed with {

Tags: matlab, indexing, octave, cell-array

I get the error

```
 struct cannot be indexed with {' in Octave.
```

What I'm trying to do is to save an array in a file by doing:

```
save myfile.mat initialW
```

The array seems to be saved ok in the file. Now I want to load it, so I wrote:

```
numberOfHiddenLayers = length(hiddenLayers);
w = cell(numberOfHiddenLayers + 1, 1);
w = load("myfile.mat");
```

However this doesn't seem to work. Any help?

`myFile.mat` looks like this:

```
# Created by Octave 5.1.0, Sat May 11 23:56:06 2019 GMT <unknown@DESKTOP-4LP8KO2>
# name: initialW
# type: global cell
# rows: 3
# columns: 1
# name: <cell-element>
# type: matrix
# rows: 8
# columns: 3
 0.11396577078177994 -0.35348554375077296 -0.075606765835858347
 -0.57613421825993738 -0.54574495840109649 -0.094554469152263232
 -0.31746528997142315 -0.46945201018320487 -0.119175071441675
 -0.23112104844315234 -0.015682264154657233 0.34987783444013509
 -0.087880331273064327 -0.19609313736912465 -0.08929095997252362
 -0.080653681379305231 0.024968754990479569 0.24949668431650684
 -0.57498895224664437 0.29920144551430461 -0.50083852142549268
 -0.3961249607134249 0.25330869897866082 0.25478925191660773


# name: <cell-element>
# type: matrix
# rows: 8
# columns: 9
 0.0037531259407581619 0.43063491636241652 -0.15445269549506291 0.47739161602226637 0.22753868435063779 -0.020492674304004144 -0.057513893868040733 -0.059060562491990765 -0.25706911999311255
 -0.29424894306440108 0.38336286612135578 -0.16776741033203713 0.46943337027631832 0.13408640078121992 -0.31554901391689794 0.35099674273923137 -0.091832499829088587 0.30933982744981386
 0.52316428666987069 0.27341366734288147 0.51082650460372281 0.49809576149309504 0.37444903641719957 0.38334119916001402 0.42842076982657767 -0.24217696807363465 0.28086557806980544
 -0.073322311691991215 0.63483655613700107 0.27533329919913868 -0.048081459516434499 -0.2267065362144246 0.64395424194737783 0.58767652657219105 0.41793542891042484 0.63321069992358114
 0.65763013238306822 0.02860044065789058 -0.011829632755802955 0.22009594392084614 -0.26511909072695583 0.57370613947506088 0.11415461587493758 0.10573792459512454 -0.32427434895492757
 0.0089604833881801182 -0.073811064790883618 -0.20709124889541619 -0.036291825999526517 0.52062296154868948 -0.011081755811460203 -0.31768168116882467 0.60905440138955669 0.17623419475038399
 -0.27776341169684216 0.61262393897374579 0.065512487276322307 -0.047081972124068172 0.55430062047934725 -0.33326753953006594 0.23202447961516875 0.17662506269733375 0.34004162952881817
 -0.046484818259064919 -0.32230299619629554 0.18841716283341831 -0.18689054271483652 0.026911300930141047 0.58017623550299824 0.12685162090341895 0.29067778228781277 0.56684018254895219


# name: <cell-element>
# type: matrix
# rows: 1
# columns: 9
 0.40736020065140749 0.31486116916450352 0.085860186186408449 -0.10247723839970202 -0.14917985837470693 0.65015717261764294 -0.1038654730028068 0.38554195073868397 -0.039542106657368348
```

Comment: Have you looked at `w`? It's a struct after the load

Answer (score 2):

When you [`load`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/load.html) a mat-file with a single output argument, it loads the data into a struct with fields that are the names of your variables. `w` is a struct with field `initialW` after you call `load`.

When you assign to a variable without any indexing expression on the left hand side, you discard the previous value. So the cell array your started with is simply overwritten by the struct.

You can do either

```
w = load(...);
w = w.initialW;
```

Or, if you want to use the cells:

```
w = cell(...);
iw = load(...);
w{1:length(iw.initialW)} = iw.initialW;
```

Comment: initialW is the same type as w. w is an array and I want to fill each position with the data in myfile.mat

Comment: Just updated my answer. You should add your first comment to the question. It's much more important than the contents of the file.